# nose tests with custom plugin never enters teardown on assertion errors

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, selenium, nose, nosetests

I have a selenium test suite run by nose.  We have written a custom plugin that pushes info to our db in `afterTest()` but this returns nothing, so it should not interfere with any of nose's normal functionality.

If a test has issues due to timeout or some other browser error, tests enter `teardown()` just fine, and nose registers an `error`.

But if a test fails on assertion error, nose registers these as `error`s (not `failure`s) and teardown() is never triggered, leaving me with lots of orphaned browsers since `self.driver.quit()` lives in `teardown()`.

For example, we have a test that performs function on our webpage which has a loading indicator.  We want to verify that the indicator disappears in a timely fashion, so we've written this function into our testing library.

```
def Check_for_global_indicator_doesnt_exist(unit_test):
     global_indicator_doesnt_exists=unit_test.wait_element_doesnt_exist_returns(".global-loading-indicator",unit_test.settings.NORMAL_WAIT)

    if global_indicator_doesnt_exists:
        logger.debug("Global Loading Indicator button disappearing in 10 seconds")

    else:
        logger.warning("Global Loading Indicator button didn't disappear in 10 seconds")
        global_indicator_LONG_WAIT=unit_test.wait_element_doesnt_exist_returns(".global-loading-indicator",unit_test.settings.LONG_WAIT)

    unit_test.assertEqual(global_indicator_LONG_WAIT, True, "Global Loading Indicator button didn't disappear even after 40 seconds")
```

When time is surpassed, this throws an assertionException like so:

```
2014-09-30 12:27:34,315 - ERROR - Check_for_global_indicator_doesnt_exist() completed  - 40.236 sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\mypath\LogUtils\logwrap.py", line 71, in decorator
value = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\mypath\Shortcuts\Selectors.py", line 696, in Check_for_global_indicator_doesnt_exist
unit_test.assertEqual(global_indicator_LONG_WAIT, True, "Global Loading Indicator button didn't disappear even after 40 seconds")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 515, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 508, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: Global Loading Indicator button didn't disappear even after 40 seconds
```

As I see it, there are two anomalies: 1) Why is nose considering these errors rather than failures? and 2) Why is the teardown() being prevented from firing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at many different examples of custom nose plugins, I found different plugins take a different number of arguments for their `addSuccess`, `addError` and `addFailure` functions.

My issue, as you may have guessed, was in the `addFailure` function.  Nose wanted me to define the function with 5 args, but I only gave it space for 4.

**Initial Code**

```
def addSuccess(self, test, capt):
    do_stuff()

def addError(self, test, capt, tb_info):
    do_error_stuff()

def addFailure(self, test, capt, tb_info):
    do_failure_stuff()
```

**Correct Code**

```
...
def addFailure(self, test, err, capt, tb_info):
    do_failure_stuff()
```

It's unfortunate that the Nose docs on custom plugins is so sparse (In fact, the official nose docs only specify 3 arguments needed for `addFailure`, even though many of the "batteries included" plugins define it with 4).  Without walking Nose's source code, I have no information in the docs about where these arguments are coming from.  But at least it's solved!